# Database support for XPATH 2.0

Tags: xml, xpath, nosql, relational-database

I'm looking for an open source solution that can support xpath 2.0 expressions. I'm thinking this would be a relational database or possibly an indexing tool like lucene. It seems like postgres's xpath() function only supports xpath 1.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in **[PsychoPath](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAC&url=http://psychopath.sourceforge.net/report.pdf&ei=9Id1UJjFN6jkiwKpg4HoCw&usg=AFQjCNHLhTrA-Nl6RYzr1yRg2OZEt-rmrw&sig2=RrTPtZevrx5NLZbdN8NaEg)**:

> **1.3 The Proposal**
>
> The goal of the PsychoPath project is developing a fully capable XPath 2.0 processor that is XML Schema aware, easily
>   extensible and available as an open source project at no cost.

**[Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com) 9.x (up to 9.1.07 -- non schema-aware version) is also available in [source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-B/9.1.0.8/)**:

**http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-B/9.1.0.8/**